# Adding new provider to QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList() using PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to get vector layer from arcgisfeatureserver in a standalone app, didn't work, so I checked what providers I got on PyCharm:

```
['gdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'ogr', 'vectortile']
```

While in QGIS I got :

```
['DB2', 'OAPIF', 'WFS', 'arcgisfeatureserver', 'arcgismapserver', 'delimitedtext', 'gdal', 'geonode', 'gpx', 'grass', 'grassraster', 'mdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'mssql', 'ogr', 'oracle', 'ows', 'postgres', 'postgresraster', 'spatialite', 'vectortile', 'virtual', 'wcs', 'wms']
```

This is how I wrote as I saw on the developer cookbook:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()
```

How can I add provider to my standalone app, so I can get layers from arcgisfeatureserver?

Answer (score 0):

So I just used:

```
 print(QgsApplication.showSettings())
```

inside QGIS. That gave me the correct prefix. And now everything works.